# jQuery как парсить дату для расчета количества дней между двумя датами

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, alert

Есть 2 input'a для даты и кнопка для расчета:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
  }

  $("#b").click(function() {
    var answer;
    var firstDate = Date.parse($('#inputFirstDate').val());
    var secondDate = Date.parse($('#inputSecondDate').val());
    alert(dateDiffInDays(firstDate, secondDate));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="firstDate" id="inputFirstDate" />
<input type="date" name="secondDate" id="inputSecondDate" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Расчитать" /> <br>
```

После попытки провернуть действия с функцией 'dateDiffInDays' с параметрами 'inputFirstDate' и 'inputSecondDate' приходит пустой alert.
Может быть ошибка в Date.parse()?
Или я еще что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) используйте просто [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
  }

  $("#b").click(function() {
    var firstDate = new Date($('#inputFirstDate').val());
    var firstDate2 = Date.parse($('#inputFirstDate').val());

    // Пример, того какой метод какое значение возвращает
    console.log('new Date', firstDate);
    console.log('Date.parse', firstDate2);

    var secondDate = new Date($('#inputSecondDate').val());
    console.log(dateDiffInDays(firstDate, secondDate));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="firstDate" id="inputFirstDate" />
<input type="date" name="secondDate" id="inputSecondDate" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Расчитать" /> <br>
```

Comment: на сайте если выполнить код все работает, а у меня почему-то выводит  : 
new Date Invalid Date
Date parce NaN
NaN

Comment: @masya1312 выведите себе в консоль это `$('#inputFirstDate').val()` и посмотрите что там будет, складывается впечатление, что не получается распарсить дату

Comment: вынес в отдельный файл — все заработало, спасибо)